# Zend MVC load config based on parameter in Url. Where is the right point dispatch/router/controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-controller

I'm defining a partner through a route based on the url e.g.

```
my.domain.com/:partner/:controller/:action
```

Now I want load the config file, databases for the partner before the front controller is called.

- Where do I locate this code?
- How do I get/set the variables/db, that they are later available in the controller?

I know I could do this through a controller helper but I guess this is not the best point to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a [controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.htm) is the way I'd do it:

```
class MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        switch($request->getParam('partner')) {
            //... do something based on the possibility
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the difference between dispatchLoopStartup and preDispatch?

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/article/11978 & http://devzone.zend.com/article/3372
That said, i just reread your question and this will occur after "the fornt controller is called". In fact, it is impossible to do what you want to do before "the fornt controller is called" b/c the parram is coming from the router and the router comes from the front controller. I think what you meant is "before the request is dispatched" in which case case the earliest hock you could use would be the routeShutdown, plus you know that this is only to occur once & preDispatch can occur multiple times. updating answer

Comment: I just put it into preDispatch and this works totally fine for me. Thx!